# Django inline model formset with 2 models

Tags: django, inline-formset

First of all, please forgive for my newbie questions. I did copy most of the code, and try to understand from Django documents.

Code as below:

models.py

```
class Order(models.Model):
  ORDER_CHOICES = (
      ('import', 'IMPORT'),
      ('export', 'EXPORT')
  )

  storage = models.ForeignKey(Storage, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
  order_type = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=ORDER_CHOICES)
  created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
  updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Item(models.Model):
  def random_barcode():
      return str(random.randint(10000000, 99999999))

  type = models.ForeignKey(Type, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
  brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  item_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, help_text='Name of goods, max 50 characters')
  barcode = models.CharField(max_length=8, default=random_barcode, unique=True)
  production_date = models.DateField()
  expired_date = models.DateField()

  def __str__(self):
      return self.item_type
```

forms.py

```
class ItemForm(ModelForm):
  class Meta:
      model = Item
      exclude = ['order',]
      fields = ['type', 'brand', 'item_name', 'production_date', 'expired_date']
ItemFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Order, Item, form=ItemForm, extra=1)
```

views.py

```
class CreatePO(CreateView):
  model = Order
  context_object_name = 'orders'
  template_name = 'storages/create_po.html'
  fields = ['order_type', 'storage',]
  *#dun't know how to write below code....*
```

1st question: how to use inline formset to write the CreatePO view?

2nd question: I need my create PO template as below picture, how to add a "Quantity" field? 
This kind of template need Javascript, right? Any alternative solution? I have no knowledge with javascript.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, move the `def random_barcode():` before `def __str__(self):` it looks so ugly formated code.

Then let's have a look in your pic, if you haven't proper experience with Javascript you can use Admin Views from Django, it's much more simple and supported by Django 2.1. Read more if you would like to give permission to everyone in a `admin-views` page https://docs.djangoproject.com/el/2.1/releases/2.1/#model-view-permission

So quantity will be just added inside `Item` class

```
quantity = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=1)
```

Also for your form, in my opinion, you need `modelform_factory`, so I suggest to read this one https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform-factory-function